# JPA Foreign Key constraint violation cannot insert Null

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a simple User and Roles entities with One to Many mapping. One user with Many roles. I am getting an error when I try to save the user entity. I am setting the Role object User before calling persist.

Below are the snap shot of entities.

User:

```
package com.petpe.ejbadmin.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.annotation.Generated;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient;


@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "User.findAll", query = "SELECT u FROM User u"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "User.findByUsernameandPassword", query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.username = :username AND u.password = :password"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "User.findByUserfirstname", query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.userfirstname = :userfirstname"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "User.findByUserlastname", query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.userlastname = :userlastname"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "User.findByPhonenumber", query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.phonenumber = :phonenumber"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "User.findByEmail", query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.email = :email"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "User.findByErpid", query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.erpid = :erpid"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "User.findByBuyerid", query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.buyerid = :buyerid"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "User.findByCreatedDate", query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.createdDate = :createdDate"),
    @NamedQuery(name=  "User.findByfirstletter",query="SELECT u FROM User u join fetch u.RoleSet ur WHERE LOWER(u.userfirstname) LIKE :firstname"),
    @NamedQuery(name=  "User.findallusers",query="From User u join fetch u.RoleSet ur")})
public class User implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = true)
    @Column(name = "USER_ID")
    private Integer userId;
    @Size(max = 120)
    @Column(name = "USERNAME")
    private String username;
    @Size(max = 60)
    @Column(name = "USERFIRSTNAME")
    private String userfirstname;
    @Size(max = 60)
    @Column(name = "USERLASTNAME")
    private String userlastname;
    @Size(max = 50)
    @Column(name = "PASSWORD")
    private String password;
    @Size(max = 20)
    @Column(name = "PHONENUMBER")
    private String phonenumber;
    // @Pattern(regexp="[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?", message="Invalid email")//if the field contains email address consider using this annotation to enforce field validation
    @Size(max = 50)
    @Column(name = "EMAIL")
    private String email;
    @Size(max = 250)
    @Column(name = "ERPID")
    private String erpid;
    @Size(max = 250)
    @Column(name = "BUYERID")
    private String buyerid;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "CREATED_DATE")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date createdDate;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Role> RoleSet;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(Integer userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public User(Integer userId, Date createdDate) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
    }

    public Integer getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(Integer userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getUserfirstname() {
        return userfirstname;
    }

    public void setUserfirstname(String userfirstname) {
        this.userfirstname = userfirstname;
    }

    public String getUserlastname() {
        return userlastname;
    }

    public void setUserlastname(String userlastname) {
        this.userlastname = userlastname;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getPhonenumber() {
        return phonenumber;
    }

    public void setPhonenumber(String phonenumber) {
        this.phonenumber = phonenumber;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getErpid() {
        return erpid;
    }

    public void setErpid(String erpid) {
        this.erpid = erpid;
    }

    public String getBuyerid() {
        return buyerid;
    }

    public void setBuyerid(String buyerid) {
        this.buyerid = buyerid;
    }

    public Date getCreatedDate() {
        return createdDate;
    }

    public void setCreatedDate(Date createdDate) {
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public Set<Role> getRoleSet() {
        return RoleSet;
    }

    public void setRoleSet(Set<Role> RoleSet) {
        this.RoleSet = RoleSet;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (userId != null ? userId.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof User)) {
            return false;
        }
        User other = (User) object;
        if ((this.userId == null && other.userId != null) || (this.userId != null && !this.userId.equals(other.userId))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[ userId=" + userId + " ]";
    }

}
```

Role:

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

```
package com.petpe.ejbadmin.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;


@Entity
@Table(name = "user_roles")
@XmlRootElement
public class Role implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "ROLEID")
    private Integer roleid;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 30)
    @Column(name = "ROLENAME")
    private String rolename;
    @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID", referencedColumnName = "USER_ID")
    @ManyToOne( fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private User user;

    public Role() {
    }

    public Role(String rolename) {
        this.rolename = rolename;
    }

    public Role(Integer roleid, String rolename) {
        this.roleid = roleid;
        this.rolename = rolename;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public Integer getRoleid() {
        return roleid;
    }

    public void setRoleid(Integer roleid) {
        this.roleid = roleid;
    }

    public String getRolename() {
        return rolename;
    }

    public void setRolename(String rolename) {
        this.rolename = rolename;
    }



    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (roleid != null ? roleid.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Role)) {
            return false;
        }
        Role other = (Role) object;
        if ((this.roleid == null && other.roleid != null) || (this.roleid != null && !this.roleid.equals(other.roleid))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[ roleid=" + roleid + " ]";
    }

}
```

Error:

```
1.Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'USER_ID', table 'pedb.pedb.user_roles'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
2.could not insert: [com.petpe.ejbadmin.entity.Role]
3.org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not insert: [com.petpe.ejbadmin.entity.Role]
4.javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not insert: [com.petpe.ejbadmin.entity.Role]
```

Setting and Persisting code:

```
public boolean AddorModifyUser(UserAdminDTO udato) {

        User usr=this.populateUserobj(udato);
        pet_em.persist(usr);

        return true;
    }

public User populateUserobj(UserAdminDTO udto)
    {
        User usr=new User();

        usr.setBuyerid(udto.getbuyerid());
        usr.setCreatedDate(new Date());
        usr.setEmail(udto.getEmail());
        usr.setErpid(udto.geterpid());
        usr.setPassword(udto.getPassword());
        usr.setPhonenumber(udto.getPhoneNumber());
        usr.setUserfirstname(udto.getFirstName());
        usr.setUserlastname(udto.getLastName());
        usr.setUsername(udto.getUserName());
        for(Role r: udto.getRole())
        {
            Set<Role> RoleSet=new HashSet<>();
            RoleSet.add(r);     
            usr.setRoleSet(RoleSet);
        }
        return usr;
    }
```

Layout of table:

[image]

Comment: Try (mappedBy = "user") and not "userId"

Comment: Why do you try to persist the user_roles before having the user in the database? This can't work

Comment: I am not persisting the roles before user. As i said in the post I am setting the couple of Roles object in the User entity and persisting the User.

Comment: Did you change mappedBy to "user" instead of "userId" ? Do you have always the same error ?

Comment: Hi Bilal. Buyer id is not the identity column. User id is the identity column and I am not setting it. The DB is fine as it allows to insert the user entity if I do not add the Role inside User.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So you have a `NOT NULL` constraint on the `USER_ID` inside the roles tables. When persisting (even with cascading relationships), the foreign key (or entity relationship) will not automagically set itself.

Most likely when creating the `Role`, you did not set the `User`, so when persisting, the provider has no idea what the `USER_ID` is, so tries to set it to null in the db, which is a violation of the db schema.

All you need to do is set the `User` for each `Role`

```
Set<Role> RoleSet=new HashSet<>();
for(Role r: udto.getRole())
{
    r.setUser(usr);   // <------
    RoleSet.add(r);     
}
usr.setRoleSet(RoleSet);
```

Also notice the `Set` is created outside the loop

#### *AND...BUT...WAIT...*

You're not out the woods yet. The above will solve the error, but you still have another problem. It's subtle and will definitely lead to hard to find bugs.

You have the `Role` id being generated.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer roleid;
```

So you don't set it when creating the role

```
Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();
Role userRole = new Role("USER");
userRole.setUser(user);
roles.add(userRole);
Role coolRole = new Role("COOL_GUY");
coolRole.setUser(user);
roles.add(coolRole);
user.setRoleSet(roles);
```

Doesn't look like a problem, but the bug is in the `hashCode`

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 0;
    hash += (roleid != null ? roleid.hashCode() : 0);
    return hash;
}
```

The `hashCode` only consists of the `roleId`. But you don't set the `roleId` because it is supposed to be generated. So when you add the roles to the `Set`, they all have the same `hashCode`, so you only ultimately add one `Role` to the `Set`, as objects in a `Set` cannot have the same `hashCode`.

To fix this, you can simply change the `hashCode` to also include the `rolename`.

While testing, I just had Netbeans generate `hashCode` and `equals`. Here's the result.

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 7;
    hash = 31 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.roleid);
    hash = 31 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.rolename);
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    final Role other = (Role) obj;
    if (!Objects.equals(this.roleid, other.roleid)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!Objects.equals(this.rolename, other.rolename)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

That should fix the bug.